Why there no constructors for associative containers to initialize a container whose size is defined when constructing it?
Sequence containers, such as vector, deque and list, all have constructors to create a container containing a specific number of elements.
std::vector:
//Constructs the vector with count copies of elements with value value.
vector( size_type count,                                                   
        const T& value,                                          
        const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );

//Constructs the vector with count default-inserted instances of T. No copies are made.
explicit vector( size_type count,
                 const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );



std::list:
//Constructs the list with count copies of elements with value value.
list( size_type count,
      const T& value,
      const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );

//Constructs the list with count default-inserted instances of T. No copies are made.
explicit list( size_type count,
               const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );


std::deque:
//Constructs the deque with count copies of elements with value value.
deque( size_type count,
       const T& value,
       const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );

//Constructs the deque with count default-inserted instances of T. No copies are made.
explicit deque( size_type count,
                const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );

Why are there no such constructors for associative containers?

What would the key be for each element?

What about default-initialized?

@John What would be the use-case? I've used associate containers quite a lot and never have I thought that they are missing this feature you mention.

@John - Default initialized means one key, so you don't have n elements in the container, but 1. Use the initializer list c'tor for that.

@StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica *multimaps perhaps? :-)

@TedLyngmo - s/elements/ranges/

@StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica .../g

What "s/elements/ranges/‘? @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica

@TedLyngmo No pratical usage.  I just wonder why no such ctors for associative containers while sequence continers have.

You have it backwards if you think it "should just be there", regardless of use case. For something to exist in any library, it should have (or had when it was added) a practical use case that is generally applicable to many situations. I think it was pointed out to you rather well why that doesn't apply to associative containers, so there is no reason to add such c'tors.

I think you probably need std::array

s/foo/bar/ is a sed command to replace string foo with bar. Adding g at the end means replacing all matches instead of one. This is a fancy way of telling someone they should've said something differently.

The STL didn't have them for associative containers, so the Standard C++ Library doesn't have them for associative containers.  STL doesn't have them because it doesn't make sense for an associative container to have them.

Try implementing one and see how it goes.

Such a constructor wouldn't be practically useful.
If you created an associative array whose elements are all equal, they would have the same key and value.  That's useless for the single-value maps and sets - you can just use the initialiser-list constructor for that; for the multi-value versions, you'd still only be able to create instances containing a multiple that single key, and there's not a compelling case to add such rarely-needed functionality to the library.
If you really need it, you could write your own function.  For example:
#include <ranges>
#include <set>

template<class Key, class Compare = std::less<Key>, class Allocator = std::allocator<Key>>
auto create_multiset_containing(std::size_t count, Key const& element,
                                const Compare& comp = Compare{},
                                const Allocator& alloc = Allocator{})
{
    return std::multiset<Key, Compare, Allocator>(std::from_range,
                                                  std::views::repeat(element, count),
                                                  comp, alloc);
}

